# OneToMany mapping on Embeddable key

Tags: java, jpa, jpql

I am attempting to build a permission rule for accessing items (stored in table `tab`) by the users (stored in table `users`). The availability whether to see something is stored in `permissions_tabs` table.

The result should be as if the statement is run (for the user with id=2):

```
SELECT project.tab.tab_id, project.tab.parent, project.tab.name
FROM project.tab
INNER JOIN project.permissions_tabs
ON project.tab.tab_id=project.permissions_tabs.tab_id
WHERE permissions_tabs.user_id=2 AND permissions_tabs.view=true;
```

I am attempting to do it via the `@OneToMany` annotation, but it fails - I receive the message:

> Deployment failed. The message was: Exception Description: The
>   @JoinColumns on the annotated element [field allowedTabs] from the
>   entity class [class
>   com.jtsmr.scheduler.persistence.entities.UsersEntity] is incomplete.
>   When the source entity class uses a composite primary key, a
>   @JoinColumn must be specified for each join column using the
>   @JoinColumns. Both the name and the referencedColumnName elements must
>   be specified in each such @JoinColumn.

Before amending the DB and adding the `permissions_tab`, it all worked. When I added it - I was unable to write the correct `@OneToMany` annotation, neither I succeeded in finding manual for my case.

If it is not possible, a solution via JPQL will suffice (I was unable to construct a join operation).

Here is my setup:

DB (creation statements for easier understanding):

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_id_UNIQUE` (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `username_UNIQUE` (`username`)
);
CREATE TABLE `tab` (
  `tab_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tab_id`)
);
CREATE TABLE `permissions_tabs` (
  `user_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `tab_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `to_view` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `to_edit` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`,`tab_id`),
  KEY `user_id_idx` (`user_id`),
  KEY `tab_id_idx` (`tab_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `tab_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tab_id`) REFERENCES `tab` (`tab_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
);
```

The JPA Mapping is as follows (functions omitted):

Tabs:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tab")
public class TabEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "tab_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long tabId;
    @Column(name = "parent", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long parent;
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

Users:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UsersEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name = "permissions_tabs",
        joinColumns
        = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns
        = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "tab_id", referencedColumnName = "tab_id")})
    private List<PermissionsTabsEntity> allowedTabs;
}
```

Primary key for the PermissionsTabsEntity class:

```
@Embeddable
public class PermissionsTabsPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;
    @Column(name = "tab_id")
    private Long tabId;
}
```

And the PermissionsTabsEntity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "permissions_tabs")
public class PermissionsTabsEntity implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PermissionsTabsPK id;
    @Column(name = "to_view")
    private boolean toView;
    @Column(name = "to_edit")
    private boolean toEdit;
}
```

Thank you in advance!